# Перенос данных между таблицами MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется таблица со схемой:

```
fst   --- xml
fName --- nvarchar(50)
```

Требуется разнести данные из этой таблицы по другим, с такой же схемой.
Знаю, что можно сделать перенос через:

```
INSERT INTO _toTable
SELECT * FROM _fromTable
```

Но это, насколько я понимаю, копирование, а не перенос в таблицу. То есть как минимум сталкиваюсь с тем, что нужно после переноса удалять данные из исходной таблицы. Объем данных достаточно большой в таблице - порядка 3тб. Поэтому, не очень хочется дублировать данные, а затем их удалять.

Есть ли альтернативы для переноса?

Comment: *Есть ли альтернативы для переноса?* Нет. Без копирования не обойтись.

Comment: @Akina а возможно ли связать процесс переноса и удаления вместе? То есть чтобы 1 запись перенеслась, она сразу же удалялась, чтобы не было гэпа по объему данных  (сначала все перенести, а потом все удалить)

Comment: Можно использовать _delete_ совместно с _output_: `DELETE FROM _fromTable OUTPUT DELETED.fst, DELETED.fName INTO _toTable(fst, fName);`, если только нет столбцов типа _identity_.

Comment: *а возможно ли связать процесс переноса и удаления вместе? То есть чтобы 1 запись перенеслась, она сразу же удалялась* Можно... правда, по одной - это уже слишком, умрёшь ждать... но никто не мешает гонять чуньками по, скажем, 1000 записей, пока в источнике есть записи. @i-one *Можно использовать delete совместно с output* А всё одно это будет копирование, только скрытое...

Comment: Также, для `OUTPUT` есть определённые ограничения, см. [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#inserting-data-returned-from-an-output-clause-into-a-table).

Comment: @Akina а в чем отличие удаления чанками и удаление по каждой записи через `OUTPUT`?

Comment: Тем, что при использовании OUTPUT транзакция будет зафиксирована только по завершении запроса - а до тех пор данные так и будут лежать на случай возможного отката. А при работе чунками после каждого чунка выполняется фиксация, и место, которое занимали удалённые записи, (формально) освобождается.

Comment: PS. Да, ничто не мешает, собственно, совместить - удалять с использованием OUTPUT, но лимитируя количество переносимых записей за один присест.

Comment: Да, лучше чанками, чтобы журнал транзакций не разрастался.